# Where does Astroslugs save game progress?

Tags: astroslugs

In what location on the filesystem does [Astroslugs](http://www.astroslugs.com/) store your progress through the game when you save in game?

I thought it was in the registry, when I played the DRM-free downloadable version. Since then, I installed the game on Desura and the back-up of the Astroslugs entries in the registry is not backing my previous progress up!

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Bit Barons GmbH\Astroslugs]
[...]
"LastProfile"="Wok"
[...]
"LevelFile"="Levels/18WUESTE5.asl"
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The savegame is a text file (extension: .profile) which lies in:

```
Desura\Common\Astroslugs\Profiles
```